# Assignment pipe (%<>%) not working under every condition

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, syntax-error, tidyverse

I am attempting to use the assignment pipe, `%<>%` in R, which I just installed. It is Mac version `4.0.2 GUI 1.72 Catalina build (7847)`. I also have `tidyverse` installed.

Here is what I try (using code from https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/compound.html):

```
library(tidyverse)
iris$Sepal.Length %<>% sqrt
x <- rnorm(100)
x %<>% abs %>% sort
```

Here is the result:

```
> library(tidyverse)
── Attaching packages ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.3.0 ──
✔ ggplot2 3.3.2     ✔ purrr   0.3.4
✔ tibble  3.0.3     ✔ dplyr   1.0.2
✔ tidyr   1.1.2     ✔ stringr 1.4.0
✔ readr   1.3.1     ✔ forcats 0.5.0
── Conflicts ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
> iris$Sepal.Length %<>% sqrt
Error in iris$Sepal.Length %<>% sqrt : could not find function "%<>%"
>     x <- rnorm(100)
>     x %<>% abs %>% sort
```

Some observations:

1. There is a conflict of `dplyr` and `stats`. I don't know what this means exactly, but it could be at the root of the issue.
2. There is an error when trying `iris$Sepal.Length %<>% sqrt`. However, there is no error when trying `x %<>% abs %>% sort`. I would have expected both to work or both to not work.

What should I do to get `%<>%` to work all the time?

Comment: This code `iris$Sepal.Length %<>% sqrt` works try updating your packages!

Comment: ... you have to attach `magrittr`, i.e. `librrary(magrittr)`. `magrittr` is not part of the core tidyverse. To the best of my knowledge only the pipe operator is available via `library(tidyverse)`.

Comment: Thanks, @stefan. Attaching `magrittr` did the trick.